# Guava's HashBasedTable cellSet()

Tags: java, guava

I have the following setup.

```
Table<Integer, Integer, Float> store = HashBasedTable.create();

int i = 0, j = 0;

for (List<String> stack_i : stacks) {
  j = 0;

  for (String entry_j : stack_i) {
    Float alpha = doSomeMagic(entry_j, token);
    if (alpha != null)
      store.put(i, j, alpha);
    j++;
  }
  i++;
}

if (store.cellSet().size() > 0) {
  for (Table.Cell<Integer, Integer, Float> cell : store.cellSet()) {
    if (cell.getValue() > max) {
      max = cell.getValue();
      maxchainIndex = cell.getRowKey();
    }
  }
}
```

The problem I am running into is I get the following JVM error:

> SEVERE: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access method com.google.common.collect.Iterators.emptyModifiableIterator()Ljava/util/Iterator; from class com.google.common.collect.StandardTable$CellIterator
>       at com.google.common.collect.StandardTable$CellIterator.(StandardTable.java:310)
>       at com.google.common.collect.StandardTable$CellIterator.(StandardTable.java:306)
>       at com.google.common.collect.StandardTable$CellSet.iterator(StandardTable.java:280)

The error occurs at line

```
for(Table.Cell<Integer,Integer,Float> cell:store.cellSet())
```

I can't see what I am doing wrong here. I've checked and the store has at least 1 item in it .

Comment: Can you please provide a code sample that we can compile and run ourselves to reproduce the error?

Answer (score 0):

Looks fine to me, I am able to run the following successfully.  Can you run it without any of the additional elements to eliminate any funny business not related to the for loop?

```
Table<Integer, Integer, Double> abc = HashBasedTable.create();
abc.put(1, 1, 10d);
for (Table.Cell<Integer, Integer, Double> x : abc.cellSet()) {
    System.out.println(x.toString());
}
```